# .stop on .mouseover or .hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to stop and resume the slide on a mouseover or hover occurrence. I basically want to stop all the scripts when .mouseover or .hover is triggered. Can anyone help me on this?

Edit: Code should work if you simply copy paste it, it is all hosted externally

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/jvojroo/DIamwjvp3/jquery.caroufredsel-6.2.0-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function() {



                $('#slider').carouFredSel({
                    width: '100%',
                    align: false,
                    items: 4,
                    items: {
                        width: $('#wrapper').width() * 0.15,
                        height: 500,
                        visible: 1,
                        minimum: 1
                    },
                    scroll: {
                        items: 1,
                        timeoutDuration: 1000,
                        onBefore: function(data) {


                            //  find current and next slide
                            var currentSlide = $('.slide.active', this),
                                nextSlide = data.items.visible,
                                _width = $('#wrapper').width();

                            //  resize currentslide to small version
                            currentSlide.stop().animate({
                                width: _width * 0.15
                            });
                            currentSlide.removeClass('active');

                            //  hide current block
                            data.items.old.add(data.items.visible).find('.slide-block').stop().fadeOut();

                            //  animate clicked slide to large size
                            nextSlide.addClass('active');
                            nextSlide.stop().animate({
                                width: _width * 0.7
                            });

                        },
                        onAfter: function(data) {
                            //  show active slide block
                            data.items.visible.last().find('.slide-block').stop().fadeIn();
                        }
                    },
                    onCreate: function(data) {

                        //  clone images for better sliding and insert them dynamacly in slider
                        var newitems = $('.slide', this).clone(true),
                            _width = $('#wrapper').width();

                        $(this).trigger('insertItem', [newitems, newitems.length, false]);

                        //  show images 
                        $('.slide', this).fadeIn();
                        $('.slide:first-child', this).addClass('active');
                        $('.slide', this).width(_width * 0.15);

                        //  enlarge first slide
                        $('.slide:first-child', this).animate({
                            width: _width * 0.7
                        });

                        //  show first title block and hide the rest
                        $(this).find('.slide-block').hide();
                        $(this).find('.slide.active .slide-block').stop().fadeIn();
                    }
                });

                //  Handle click events
                $('#slider').children().click(function() {
                    $('#slider').trigger('slideTo', [this]);
                });

                $('.slide:firstchild').mouseover(function() {
                    $('.slide:firstchild').stop();
                });

                $('#slider').children().mouseover(function() {
                    $('#slider').stop();
                });

                //$('#slider').children().mouseout(function() {
                //  $('#slider').trigger( 'slideTo', [this] );
                //});

                //  Enable code below if you want to support browser resizing
                $(window).resize(function() {

                    var slider = $('#slider'),
                        _width = $('#wrapper').width();

                    //  show images
                    slider.find('.slide').width(_width * 0.15);

                    //  enlarge first slide
                    slider.find('.slide.active').width(_width * 0.7);

                    //  update item width config
                    slider.trigger('configuration', ['items.width', _width * 0.15]);
                });

            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            body {
                background: #f9f9f3;
            }
            body * {
                font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #222;
                line-height: 20px;
            }
            #wrapper {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 650px;
                min-width: 900px;
                padding-top: 1px;
            }
            #slider {
                margin: 100px 0 0 0;
                height: 500px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #slider .slide {
                position: relative;
                display: none;
                height: 500px;
                float: left;
                background-position: center right;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-left: 1px solid #fff;
            }
            #slider .slide:first-child {
                border: none;
            }
            #slider .slide.active {
                cursor: default;
            }
            #slider .slide-block {
                position: absolute;
                left: 40px;
                bottom: 75px;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 435px;
                background-color: #fff;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
                padding: 20px;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #134B94;
                border: 1px solid #fff;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            #slider .slide-block h4 {
                font-size: 36px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 0 0 10px 0;
                line-height: 1;
            }
            #slider .slide-block p {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #donate-spacer {
                height: 0;
            }
            #donate {
                border-top: 1px solid #999;
                width: 750px;
                padding: 50px 75px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #donate p, #donate form {
                margin: 0;
                float: left;
            }
            #donate p {
                width: 650px;
                color: #999;
            }
            #donate form {
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="slider">
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3821/10956569263_92a647e267_o.png">
                    <div class="slide-block">
                            <h4>Ice Age</h4>

                        <p>Heading south to avoid a bad case of global frostbite, a group of migrating misfit creatures embark on a hilarious quest to reunite a human baby with his tribe.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7444/10956575693_94fd773731_o.png">
                    <div class="slide-block">
                            <h4>For The Birds</h4>

                        <p>For the Birds is an animated short film, produced by Pixar Animation Studios released in 2000. It is shown in a theatrical release of the 2001 Pixar feature film Monsters, Inc.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3789/10956504824_4845433ff6_o.png">
                    <div class="slide-block">
                            <h4>UP</h4>

                        <p>A comedy adventure in which 78-year-old Carl Fredricksen fulfills his dream of a great adventure when he ties thousands of balloons to his house and flies away to the wilds of South America.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5464/9449526762_ed5339251e_o.jpg">
                    <div class="slide-block">
                            <h4>Ice Age</h4>

                        <p>Heading south to avoid a bad case of global frostbite, a group of migrating misfit creatures embark on a hilarious quest to reunite a human baby with his tribe.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: fiddle? I'm new sorry haha :)

Comment: Just have to copy paste your code that's all and generated link to put here

Comment: Posted in full code, will work if you copy paste it

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> Uhh add in this, not going in post for some reason :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger a custom event named "stop" on carouFredSel component If you want to stop the slider.

```
$('#slider').trigger("stop");
```

And trigger a custom event named "play" with a extra parameter true to resume the slider

```
$("#slider").trigger("play",true);
```

For example:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#slider").carouFredSel({
            items: 4
        });

        $("#slider > div.slide").hover(
            function(){
                $("#slider").trigger("stop");
            },
            function(){
                $("#slider").trigger("play",true);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm! Can you explain exactly how this works? I'd like to know this for next time. I'd vote up, but I have 1 reputation haha :D

Comment: Ahh figured it out. Cheers for all the help.

Comment: You're welcome : ) You could reference [official document](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/custom-events.php) when you want to do some customization.